# setTitle for QDialog not works on linux

Tags: qt, qt4

I am using

```
setTitle(tr("Data parameters")); // customized QDialog class
```

In windows its showing the Title fully(Data parameters") but in Ubunthu its showing only "Data"

I tried

```
setTitle(QString("Data parameters"));
```

Comment: Works for me. Maybe the word "parameters" does not fit in the header?

Comment: Try `setWindowTitle`

Comment: You didn't provide a [mcve]; shame on you for relying on people's crystal balls! What does `setTitle()` do?